# How to properly run Django dev server locally for testing form another device in the network

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a local dev server on Django using the command

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

but it takes very long time loading whenever I try to open it, and in the cmd, it shows this error

```
 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

**Note** Using Postgresql as a database.

**Traceback**

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53334)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in your settings.py file and add : `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['(your IP)']`
Then, if you type `python manage.py runserver (your IP)`, you should be able to access your website from any device connected to the same wifi/network.